# Can't add sql rows to a javascript array in node js

Tags: arrays, sqlite, nodes, element

So I want to query some data from an sql database (specifically sqlite), and to put the results in an array. However it doesn't seem to work and I only get an empty array. here's how I tried to do it:

```
var boards = []; // init the boards array
const sqlite = require('sqlite3').verbose(); // init sqlite
var db = new sqlite.Database("database.db"); // init the database

// the query
db.all(`select * from boards;`,(err, result) => {
    // error handling
    if (err) throw err;
    // loop threw all the results and add them to the boards array
    result.forEach((row) => {
        boards.push(row);
    });
});
console.log(boards);
// outputs [], even if there's something in the boards table
```

I tried doing things like replacing

```
        boards.push(row);
```

with

```
        boards[boards.length] = row;
```

and replacing the entire forEach function with

```
    boards = result;
```

But none of it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log(boards);
```

... is running before the db returns. Your code will:

1. send the db call
2. log `boards`
3. (when the db call returns): add rows to `boards`

You need to log `boards` inside your callback

Comment: see https://nodejs.dev/learn/javascript-asynchronous-programming-and-callbacks